# Div not filling parent when using absolute positioning and display: table

Tags: css, firefox, position, margin

I am using a piece of code to vertically centre a div inside another div. In safari/chrome/etc (webkit) the following works:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
display:table;
```

but on firefox this does not work, why is this and how can i fix it.

P.S. I'm using the latest versions of all browsers

Please check my fiddle to see the problem in action.

http://jsfiddle.net/matt3224/prx7o1yx/

Comment: I'd be surprised if it worked on Chrome/Safari. The point is that `width`/`height` of the `<div>` (which is a non-replaced block level element) MUST be specified explicitly.

Comment: @HashemQolami Why surprised? http://jsfiddle.net/hunp4eh1/1/ Works fine as long as the parent has a height

Comment: @3rror404 Because it does NOT `vertically centre a div inside another div` but it does stretch the `div` to cover the whole box's containing block

Comment: Which is what I'm assuming he is trying to do given the title `Div not filling parent when using absolute positioning` . Perhaps OP needs to clarify

Comment: Hashem, yes you are correct my question doesn't completely make since given my example. i am using display:table; on this div also and on the child div i'm using display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; So the end result is vertically centering

Comment: Updated question with fiddle link

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```css
.parent-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.child-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 296px;
  height: 296px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">     
  <!-- Parent DIV -->     
  <div class="child-div">     
    <!-- Child DIV -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't, and can't know the height of this element